# Spring ACL Voters configuration

Tags: spring, spring-security, acl, spring-security-acl

So I have tried to implement a simple ACL example in my project and everything works as it should. I have the following configuration:

```
<property name="decisionVoters">

    <list>

        <ref bean="categoryReadVoter"/>

    </list>

</property>
```

```
<constructor-arg ref="mutableAclService"/>

<constructor-arg value="VOTE_CATEGORY_READ"/>

<constructor-arg>

    <array>

        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.security.acls.domain.Ba sePermission.READ"/>

    </array>

</constructor-arg>

<property name="processDomainObjectClass" value="packet.Group"/>
```

Now, I have about 30 Entities in my project and I want to define at least 4 roles for each (create, read, write, administrate). Do I have to define a bean for each entity-role pair? Is there a simpler way to do this? Do I always have to set a specific class for a voter using  ?

New features and new Entities and roles are also to be expected in this project. Do I have to configure each new Entity and role in my config file or is there a more general way to do this. Could you please point me to some examples or docu?

I am currently using Spring Security 3.1.

Thanks

P.S. I have already posted my questions in the Spring Security Forum but thought I'd give this a try as well

Answer (score 0):

So I have found the answer.
You can use a interface instead of an entity and let the entity implement the interface.

Comment: Hey, can you tell me more details about that or give me a link on the forum. thanks